# syncing firebase data over multiple users for a quiz app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to make a quiz app that has a given time count down limit to give answers to a particular question. the app is intended to be used by many users all at the same time using the same time count down data, basically all users should be in sync with the same time limit to answer a question before moving to the next question. the question is how can i make this app using flutter and firebase? is firebase capable of doing this?

Comment: Yup, sounds doable. How to build such an app is well beyond what we can reasonably answer on Stack Overflow though. I recommend starting with one of the codelabs or tutorials out there, and/or with the documentation of Firebase.

Comment: As frank suggested go through the tutorials, you can also check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixWtgO22hBE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use firestore to do this.

1. Firestore can support at most 1 million realtime connections at the same time. So usually you don't need to worry about the network limitation.
2. For the time count down, you probably need to consider about the delay of network. Instead of syncing the count down time every moment, you can sync the start time and the end time with the server, then let the app count down the time locally.